# Finder Sync Extension

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, finder, findersync

I need to write a simple **command line tool (daemon) in swift with the Finder Sync Extension**. So I created a sample command line tool app and added a target with Finder Synch Extension. But when I ran the project only command line tool app process is creating and not the finder Synch Extension. Can any one give me the direction how to create a Finder Sync Extension for Command line tool app?

Comment: Have a look at apple documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html

Comment: Did you get any solution?